# JSP : Hidden field is not getting submitted

Tags: jsp, forms

I am using following code in JSP file,but I see that the value of hidden field is not getting submitted

```
<form action="/processor/RequestActivityByCsv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="inputDiv">
   <h5>comma delimited file: <input type="file" name="file"/></h5>
   <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" value="<%=CryptoUtils.generateCsrfToken()%>" />
   <input type="submit" value="upload" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</div>
</form>
```

in the page source this comes as :

```
<form action="/processor/RequestActivityByCsv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="inputDiv">
         <h5>comma delimited file: <input type="file" name="file"/></h5>
         <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" value="t5ipRVFNIP83IUh5NCf7PiTp4mM2kBFVdHjqwlGx7PI=" />
         <input type="submit" value="upload" class="btn btn-primary"/>
      </div>
 </form>
```

anything obvious I mignt be missing here ?

Comment: what's your get parameter code ?

Comment: doing req.getParameter() in java gives null

Comment: I guess the problem is with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as only file is being submitted,no other field is getting submitted.any ideas ?

Comment: Try the posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the hidden field as well as all other field values using

```
String value = request.getParameter("fieldname").toString();
```

In your case for getting the hidden value for the field na

```
String csrfToken= request.getParameter("csrfToken").toString();
```

**UPDATION 2**

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.jsp" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" id="csrfToken"  value="t5ipRVFNIP83IUh5NCf7PiTp4mM2kBFVdHjqwlGx7PI=" />
        <input type="submit" value="sumbit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        String csrfToken= (String)request.getParameter("csrfToken");
        out.print(csrfToken);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT**

t5ipRVFNIP83IUh5NCf7PiTp4mM2kBFVdHjqwlGx7PI=

Comment: this will just give a NullPointerException as  req.getParameter("csrfToken") is giving null

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have faced this problem before.

Try this :-

```
<form name="frmfileupload" action="/processor/RequestActivityByCsv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="inputDiv">
   <h5>comma delimited file: <input type="file" name="file"/></h5>
   <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" value="<%=CryptoUtils.generateCsrfToken()%>" />
   <input type="button" value="upload" onclick="funSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Use Java script to submit the form:-

```
<script >
 function funSubmit(){

    //You can do javascript validation here 
    var val=document.frmfileupload.csrToken.value;
    document.frmfileupload.action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/processor/RequestActivityByCsv?csrToken="+val;
    document.frmfileupload.submit();

}

</script>
```

In the above java script I am sending the token value by using URL.

Hope it will help you.